# Page not loading in Vite + React + Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, react-typescript

[image]

This is my first time using Vite so maybe it's just an easy fix that I'm not seeing. I have no errors in the console.

index.tsx

```
function LoadingComponent(props: any) {
    return <div />;
}

/**
 * Locomotive has a problem in prod build.
 * A lazy load of the component fixes it
 */
const HomeLazy = Loadable({
    loader: () => import('./containers/Home'),
    loading: LoadingComponent,
});

const Index = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <HomeLazy />
        </>
    );
};
export default Index;
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="Index"></div>
    <script type="module" src="./src/index.tsx"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.body.style.cursor = 'none';
</script>
  </body>
```

I switched out the `main.tsx` for an `index.tsx`. But once I did that and tried to load everything with a lazy load, that's when it broke. But using a normal react app it works.

Comment: Your index.tsx appears to be missing the `createRoute` call. See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-client.html#createroot. Add  `createRoot(document.querySelector('#Index')).render(<Index>);` to the bottom of `index.tsx`